# Is it possible to search for sections of a website by color using the console application in a browser?

Tags: javascript, web, browser

For example, suppose I visit a very long webpage that would print 500+ pages. Throughout this webpage, there are a few words highlighted using a light green color. Is there a way to search for words highlighted with this color using the CLI in Chrome?

Comment: Your question is vague but the normal solution with any reasonable site would be to type `document.querySelectorAll(".classWhichGivesThatStyle")`

Comment: Suppose you are a student in a class. Your professor provides you with a single, gigantic webpage containing his lecture notes. He periodically highlights important words in light green. I want to be able to find all the words that are highlighted in that color.

Comment: Assuming it's not 1995, you don't directly give colors to elements on the web, you give them a class. So you can easily use `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one is to inspect the text, and inspect the highlighet part. Highlight text can be done in various number of ways. Just to name a few:

```
<body>
Here is an example of <mark>highlight text</mark> using mark
Here is an example of <span class="highlight">highlight text</span> using span with class
Here is an example of <span style="background-color: #FFFF00">highlight text</span> using span with style
</body>
```

My guess is that `<span class="highlight">` is used (but probably with a different name of the class).

So, depending on in what way the text is highlight you find it using differnt commands in the CLI. When you know in what way the page is highlight the text ,you can start finding it by (for examples above):

```
document.querySelectorAll("mark")
document.querySelectorAll(".highlight")
document.querySelectorAll("span[style^='background-color:']")
```

Comment: Quick followup question. The data that I need is in the textContent field. Is there a way to suppress the other fields within that class?

Comment: I am nut sure i understand the question. But `document.querySelectorAll(".owner")` will give you an array. And to get the text/content of the "first" item, you do `document.querySelectorAll(".owner")[0].textContent`. And similary for the second `[1]` item and so on.

Comment: That's what I needed! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, the highlighted elements probably have a class that gives that highlight color, if so, you can use `document.querySelectiorAll('.highlight_class')`

If the style is directly on the HTML element you can find the elements with regex.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not sure of whether the background color is added using class or inline style, use the following:

```js
const paras = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('p'));
const output = paras.filter(para => window.getComputedStyle(para).getPropertyValue('background-color') === 'green');
```

It will give you array of paragraphs having the background color green. Change the values accordingly to get the desired result.